# Active link on navigation using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I can't seem to figure out how to make my site navigation have an active link for the current page.

This is the only code that is working for me, however, there is always two links with the class "active." I only want the current page to be active.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
 function setActive() {
 aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
 if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
  aObj[i].className='active';
  }
 }
}

window.onload = setActive;
</script>
```

Here is my staging site: http://champhero.wpengine.com

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Doesn't the wordpress theme (or wordpress itself) already add `active` to the current menu item?

Comment: @PatrickEvans it would, if OP was actually using WP menu functionality, but looking at the site's source code I suspect that's not the case. (But it should be, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking an indexOf. Therefore, URL http://champhero.wpengine.com/ is always contained in others like http://champhero.wpengine.com/the-enemies/

If you just check an equality, it should work:

```
function setActive() {
    var aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) { 
        if (document.location.href == aObj[i].href) {
            aObj[i].className = 'active';
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You were not declaring local variables with 'var', making them globals and potentially unstable across the environment. i changed that in my suggested code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I added the script and it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add: window.onload = setActive;

Answer (score 0):

`a` tag href contains whole link so you could check for equality like below.

```
<script>
  function setActive() {
    aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
      if(document.location.href === aObj[i].href) {
        aObj[i].className='active';
      }
    }
  }

  window.onload = setActive;
</script>
```

Home page nav link(`http://champhero.wpengine.com/`) is highlighted in every page because it's present in all other links(`http://champhero.wpengine.com/pagelink`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i)
        if (anchors[i].href === window.location.href) 
            anchors[i].className += ' active';
};
</script>
```

though this snippet will apply the class to all anchors. For just the ones in, say, your navigation bar, give them a specific CSS class to hook into and then:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var nav_links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
    for (var i = 0; i < nav_links.length; ++i)
        if (nav_links[i].href === window.location.href) 
            nav_links[i].className += ' active';
};
</script>
```